# Auto TimeStamp new entry to DB (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, timestamp, phpmyadmin

If I want each new entry into my db to be automatically timestamped, would I set the Field Type to "timestamp" and have the Default value set to "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"?

Is this the correct method?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That is correct. In SQL code that would be:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    ...
    `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this method is correct:

```
 create table t(Id int, ts timestamp default current_timestamp)

 insert into t(Id) values (1)

 select * from t

 1;2010-09-01 09:20:09:000
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a big help

Comment: Since this is timestamp, shouldn't it be shown as a number of seconds rather than as date time.

Comment: @Foreever this is mysql date/timestamp, not javascript nor iso8601. NOTE that it also returns in "server time", which can be different from UTC