# PHP mysql auto insert timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Say I have a table name auto_parts with these fields.
`id, part, price, timestamp`
and I insert a new row via php as so:

```
$query = "insert into auto_parts(id, part, price, timestamp)
  values(1, 'axle', 200)"
mysql_query($query);
```

will that automatically add the timestamp.
Or do I have to insert a value for timestamp myself?

Comment: What is your table structure?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you need to do is declare `timestamp` to be of type in your sql

```
timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and modify the query to

```
$query = "insert into auto_parts(id, part, price)
  values(1, 'axle', 200)"
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: you can use only one timestamp variable per table !!

Comment: Only one *automatic* timestamp per table, whether via DEFAULT or UPDATE (though I think that's changed in recent MySQL versions). You can have multiple timestamp columns, as long as no more than one is set/updated automatically. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 11):

```
$query = "insert into auto_parts(id, part, price, timestamp)
  values(1, 'axle', 200, 'NOW()')"
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: It is convenient when you have more than 1 `timestamp` column (and one is automatic, see [Sven Viking comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662898/php-mysql-auto-insert-timestamp#comment20686941_8662912) for details) and want to update/insert a new data in one other timestamp column.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in SQL itself instead of passing it ... its more efficient ... This is the corresponding post:

[Auto TimeStamp new entry to DB (phpMyAdmin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615471/auto-timestamp-new-entry-to-db-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

I know there are already answers to this question so I am kind of combining all answers and explaining a little bit.
There may be two ways to do this,

1. Change your table and make timestamp column to default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

> ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

and modify your query like this, timestamp will be inserted automatically

> $query = "insert into auto_parts(id, part, price) values(1, 'axle',
>   200)";  mysql_query($query);

2. If you have more than one timestamp table then you can make one as current timestamp and for other one use like this

> ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL

and modify your query like this

> $query = "insert into auto_parts(id, part, price, timestamp) values (1, 'axle', 200, now())"; mysql_query($query);