# How to insert into database date and time?

Tags: php, html

I'm making a website and when the user click on button I want it to send at what time and day the user clicked on my button, here is my code:

Button:

```
<form method="POST">
    <button name="btn">Click Here</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I would do this on the database end. When you do your insert into the database just leave the timestamp field out of your query. The databse would auto insert the current timestamp. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615471/auto-timestamp-new-entry-to-db-phpmyadmin

Comment: why do questions like these get answers with no code they tried, is beyond me.

Comment: why did OP chose that answer though?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using mysql and have a database for date types setup you can do this:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
$query = "INSERT INTO `time` VALUES ('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')";
//check upload

if(mysql_query($query)){
    echo "Date and Time are added";
}
}
<form method="POST">
<button name="btn">Click Here</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you are not seriously writing an answer with old, deprecated, unsecure `mysql_*` functions, are you?

Comment: looks like you copied this from your project. `$this->dbName` `mysqli()` how do you know the OP is using`mysqli()`?

Comment: @user8859191 Yes, it is outdated. Years ago.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using PHP to insert data into DB use PHP function

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:sa')
```